# Read a Text file having row in parenthesis and values separated by comma using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to read a text file which contains data in parenthesis as row and values in it as column.The format of txt file is below :

```
(a, b, c, d) (a1, b1, (c1,c12,c13), d1) (a2, b2, (c2,c22,c23), d2) (a3, b3, (c3,c32,c33), d3) (a4, b4, (c4,c42,c43), d4)
```

I want the data in this format :

```
a  b  c  d
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
a3 b3 c3 d3
a4 b4 c4 d4
```

When i am reading text file as csv file it reads all the data in one row only. It shows 1 row and all the columns.
Please help me with this problem.

Comment: which result do you obtain when reading your csv file ? you have to me more precise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With builtin `pandas` functions (perhaps faster with large dataframe), you can use:

```py
# Use the standard `read_csv` function of pandas.
# Note the lineterminator option.
df = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep=",", lineterminator=")")
# rename the 1st column (remove 1st char)
df.columns.values[0] = df.columns.values[0][1:]
# remove the opening parenthesis for the 1st columns:
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].str.replace('^\ ?\(', '')
# remove the last line:
df = df[:-1]  
print(df)
```

Comment: @pyOlive This `df = df[:-1]` is unnecessary and should be removed.

Comment: It is usefull because the file ends with `)` which add an additionnal row filled with nan values to the dataframe

Comment: Note: I've edited my answer to built a more robust regex

Comment: I guess  using `df = df[:-1] ` would cutoff the last line f`(a4, b4, c4, d4)` from the result. Although, Nice answer +1.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Where Input_file is your actual file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re

f = open("Input_file", "r")
text=f.read()
f.close()
text2=''
if ' ' in text:
    text2 = re.sub('^\\(|,|\\)\n$|\\)$','',text)
    text2 = text2.replace(') (' , '\n')
    text2 = text2.replace('\\)','\n')
    text2 = re.sub('\\)|\\(','',text2)
    print(text2)
```

***Proof of concept:*** Let's say following is Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
(a, b, c, d) (a1, b1, c1, d1) (a2, b2, c2, d2) (a3, b3, c3, d3) (a4, b4, c4, d4)
(a, b, c, d) (a1, b1, c1, d1) (a2, b2, c2, d2) (a3, b3, c3, d3) (a4, b4, c4, d4)
```

When we run script output will be as follows.

```
./script.py
a b c d
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
a3 b3 c3 d3
a4 b4 c4 d4
a b c d
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
a3 b3 c3 d3
a4 b4 c4 d4
```

---

---

***Detailed explanation:*** Reading Input_file complete content and saving it to variable `text`.  Now closing that file by `close`  command. Now with a for loop going  through all contents of Input_file which are stored in variable `text`. Then substituting starting `)`, ending `)\n` and `,` with NULL in all lines. Now replacing starting `(` with NULL and then replacing `) (` with new line for all occurrences to make output look like OP's request.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = """(a, b, c, d) (a1, b1, c1, d1) (a2, b2, c2, d2) (a3, b3, c3, d3) (a4, b4, c4, d4)
"""

#the sep argument says look for whitespace between ) and (
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None,sep='(?<=\))\s(?=\()',engine='python')

df = (df
      #transpose puts them into individual rows
      .T[0]
      #remove parentheses
      .str.strip("()")
      #now we can safely split and create a new dataframe
      .str.split(",",expand=True)
     )

#assign the first row as the columns
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
#assign the rest as the dataframe
df = df.iloc[1:]

df
    a   b   c   d
1   a1  b1  c1  d1
2   a2  b2  c2  d2
3   a3  b3  c3  d3
4   a4  b4  c4  d4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a slicker and more Pythonic way, but here is a quick and dirty function that you can build on

```
def str_parser(in_str): 
     out_str = "" 
     while(in_str != ""): 
         first_idx, last_idx = in_str.index("("), in_str.index(")") 
         sub_str = in_str[first_idx+1: last_idx] 
         out_str += (sub_str.replace(",", "") + "\n") 
         in_str = in_str[last_idx+1:] 
     return out_str
```

Input:

```
print(str_parser("(a, b, c, d) (a1, b1, c1, d1) (a2, b2, c2, d2) (a3, b3, c3, d3) (a4, b4, c4, d4)"))
```

Output:

```
a b c d
a1 b1 c1 d1
a2 b2 c2 d2
a3 b3 c3 d3
a4 b4 c4 d4
```